# Check if Cantor’s Theorem is applicable in the following examples. Also, find $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb{N}} F_n$ in each case

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

So we have to find whether Cantor's Theorem is applicable to the following
(i) $F_n = [n, \infty)$ (ii) $F_n = (0, \frac{1}{n})$ (iii) $F_n = [1 − \frac{1}{n} , 2 + \frac{1}{n}]$

Now I've tried doing these as

1. $F_n$ is non-empty and closed and $[n+1,\infty)\subset[n,\infty)$. But since $n\to\infty$, the length of $F_n$ does not tend to $0$. So not applicable
2. $F_n$ is an open interval so not applicable
3. $F_n$ is non-empty and closed. But as $n\to\infty$, $F_n\to [1,2]$ and length $[1,2]$ is not equal to $0$. So not applicable.

Is my method correct or am I doing something wrong??

Comment: Your answers are correct .

Comment: what do you mean by "applicable"?

Comment: @Lorenzo Do the conditions apply: i.e. are the $F_n$ closed non-empty and nested and do their diameters tend to $0$? We're working in $\Bbb R$ so that condition is OK.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason that a condition in i. fails, is to note that for all $n$, $\operatorname{diam}(F_n)=+\infty$ and it follows from that that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{diam}(F_n) =+\infty$ in particular, so the diameters do not tend to $0$ as they should.

Another condition in ii. fails because $F_n$ is **not closed** (that it's an open interval is *not* relevant, as open does **not** always imply it's not closed). In both i. and ii. we have $\bigcap_n F_n = \emptyset$, so the conclusion fails too, showing the necessity of the diamater resp. closedness conditions.

For iii. again $\operatorname{diam}(F_n) = 1+\frac{2}{n} \to 1$, so it does not apply (limit not $0$). But indeed $\bigcap_n F_n = [1,2]$, as you claimed. So the conclusion fails too: the intersection is not a singleton.

You should be more precise in checking the conditions. That the conclusion of the theorem fails indicates that not all conditions of the theorem are fulfilled, but you're asked to say *which* condition exactly fails *how*...

Answer (score -1):

Note that the exact statement of Cantor’s Intersection Theorem is the following:

> The intersection of any decreasing sequence of non-empty nested compact sets is non-empty.

Thus, as you correctly stated, it is not applicable in cases a) and b). However, it is clearly applicable in case c), since that sequence satisfies all of the assumptions of Cantor’s Theorem.

Comment: No, Cantor's theorem states that if $(X,d)$ is complete and $(F_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of closed non-empty sets such that $\textrm{diam}(F_n) \to 0$ then $\bigcap_n F_n$ is a singleton.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma that is indeed a form of the Theorem in the case of complete metric spaces. However, you should be aware that what i wrote in my answer is the topological version of Cantor’s Intersection Theorem. If you are not, I recommend you do some research first. Also OP did not mention in his statement which version of the Theorem he is interested in, so my answer is rather valid.

Comment: No, he checks diameters in his answer so he definitely means the above version in a metric space. Of course much more general versions of this exist. But the above is the "Urversion" by Cantor himself (which he used to show that $\Bbb R$ is uncountable (original proof)).

Comment: Cantor did not know the concept of compactness yet. He comes before that.

Comment: That does not mean that my answer is wrong or not valid. Anyhow, you do you, boo.

Comment: It doesn't apply as this is not the version the OP uses. He does not mention compactness either. It's also not a critique of his attempt.